# "git pull" or "git merge" between master and development branches

Tags: git, workflow

I have my `master` branch and a `develop` branch for working on a few changes. I need to merge changes from `master` into `develop`, but will eventually merge everything from `develop` into `master`. I  have two different workflows in mind:

1. `git pull origin master` into `develop` branch
2. `git merge master` into `develop` branch

Which is the best way to do this, and why?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge FETCH_HEAD`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Be careful with rebase. If you're sharing your develop branch with anybody, rebase can make a mess of things. Rebase is good only for your own local branches.

Rule of thumb, if you've pushed the branch to origin, don't use rebase. Instead, use merge.

Comment: Yet is it safe to rebase and a `git push origin rebasedBranch --force` on a private repo? The only user is  myself.

Comment: Yes, if you're the only user, of course it is safe. I use git push --force all the time when I'm the only user. :)

Comment: I echo Eric's warning. Although, it's perfectly okay to rebase your own remote branch too. Play around with both rebase and merge and you will understand the pros and cons of each and learn when to use them.

Comment: Good article on using rebase, even merging after resolving conflicts: https://github.com/everpix/Everpix-Intelligence

Comment: @IanLotinsky your link doesn't point to an article on rebase. Longshot, but do you still have the correct link? :)

Comment: I don’t get this answer, the question was about which one to use between pull or merge, not rebase.

Answer (score 356):

This workflow works best for me:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

...make some changes...

...notice master has been updated...

...commit changes to develop...

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

...bring those changes back into develop...

```
git checkout develop
git rebase master
```

...make some more changes...

...commit them to develop...

...merge them into master...

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge develop
```

Comment: This is how I work too, and I find it works well. There's one thing I don't do though, and that's the `git pull` right before the final `git merge develop`. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: After the ...notice master has been updated... part, wouldn't the checkout master wipe your local changes to develop if you not commit them?

Comment: @a1an No, but if you don't commit them then the changes will move over to the master branch and git won't let you pull until they have been committed.

Comment: @Ian Lotinsky when working on 'develop' how could you tell that 'master' had been updated?

Comment: @zkent, git pull would pull any changes down.

Comment: @zkent because at times there are those who commit on master, no matter what!

Comment: @crdx Chances are that other branches are merged to remote master before you merge your branch to your local master. You pull and bring remote master changes to your local copy of master. This is how I understood it.

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin master` on your develop branch is a bit faster.

Comment: I need to clarify something: This answer assumes that `develop` branch is **not** shared across multiple users, right? Or, would this solution work if we had a `master` and a `develop` branch that were being pulled by multiple users? For example, if each user would typically send PR's of their feature branches into `develop`, but some hot fixes were applied to `master`, how would we update the hotfixed changes onto our `develop` branch? It seems like rebasing a shared `develop` branch is bad news for other users, because it would require one to push-force the rebased `develop` branch.

Comment: Remember to `git push` your changes to the `master` branch after the steps above! Might sound really basic but I forget sometimes and wonder where my changes are lol.

Answer (score 26):

The best approach for this sort of thing is probably [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).  It allows you to pull changes from master into your development branch, but leave all of your development work "on top of" (later in the commit log) the stuff from master.  When your new work is complete, the merge back to master is then very straightforward.

Comment: Good advice, assuming `develop` isn't shared with anyone else.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt If `develop` **is shared** with other contributors, how would we update `develop` when some hotfixes were pushed directly to `master`? Should we do a merge, ie `git checkout master && git pull --rebase && git checkout develop && git merge master`? I left a comment on the highest voted answer above, which also details this concern.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not sharing develop branch with anybody, then I would just rebase it every time master updated, that way you will not have merge commits all over your history once you will merge develop back into master. Workflow in this case would be as follows:

```
> git clone git://<remote_repo_path>/ <local_repo>
> cd <local_repo>
> git checkout -b develop
....do a lot of work on develop
....do all the commits
> git pull origin master
> git rebase master develop
```

Above steps will ensure that your develop branch will be always on top of the latest changes from the master branch. Once you are done with develop branch and it's rebased to the latest changes on master you can just merge it back:

```
> git checkout -b master
> git merge develop
> git branch -d develop
```

Answer (score 1):

my rule of thumb is:

> `rebase` for branches with the *same name*, `merge` otherwise.

examples for same names would be `master`, `origin/master` and `otherRemote/master`.

if `develop` exists only in the local repository, and it is always based on a recent `origin/master` commit, you should call it `master`, and work there directly. it simplifies your life, and presents things as they actually are: you are directly developing on the `master` branch.

if `develop` is shared, it should not be rebased on `master`, just merged back into it with `--no-ff`. you are developing on `develop`. `master` and `develop` have different names, because we want them to be different things, and stay separate. do not make them same with `rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `git pull origin <branch_name>` over to the branch I am looking to merge into.
I infact haven't ever used `git merge <branch_name>`

Reason, I used to get a bug with it in GitLab when I had started to use it.
But now it is more logical as well... because `git pull` does:
(a) `git fetch`
(b) `git merge`

2 commands vs one; makes it no brainer application to keep work going fast.

PS: if you aren't sure what might come, it might be better to use the 'broken down' commands there right  ;)