# github/egit/git: compare master with an earlier commit and merge selected changes into a new branch. how?

Tags: git, github, merge, egit, git-merge

DESIRED

I am a sole developer (and a beginner). I have a master branch only at the moment. Within it, I have some commits that are really different versions with different types of implementations. So, I want to make them into new branches. But I also have some functionality in the master branch that I want to merge down to these new branches. These functionality is minor and I would like to see and pick the changes precisely.

TRIED

In Egit, if I make a new branch the master files are deleted locally. So, I do not understand how I can compare versions. Can I have several branches available locally? Is it desirable? How?

If I ask to merge my master into my new branch, Egit does a fast-forward showing no conflicts or comparisons, not what I want.

REQUEST

What would be a good process to achieve my desired outcome? I am happy to mix Egit with GitBash if necessary (presuming they can mix with no problems).

BACKGROUND

A lot of similar discussion ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556467/git-pull-or-git-merge-between-master-and-development-branches) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916329/cleanup-git-master-branch-and-move-some-commit-to-new-branch), for example) or relevant tutorials (e.g., [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/30/merging-branches-in-eclipse-git-egit/)) but no precise match.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a facility called **cherry-picking**.

If you have Git installed:

1. create a branch
2. Use the `gitk --all` command which shows a nice GUI about the commits of all branches you have.
3. You can easily select the required commits and simply right-click on it and select *"Cherry-pick this commit"*.

That's all.

Comment: Thanks. What I need to do is to pick changes from several commits, actually. So, I need to have the changes displayed side by side and integrated semi-manually. Maybe I shall just have to do it by hand... But I was hoping to hear what the proper way could be...

Comment: Hm, ain't sure if I understand your needs correctly, but [here's a screenshot about gitk](http://orestis.gr/static/upload/blog_images/2009/06/17/gitk.png): it does display changes side by side. It does the cherry-pick automatically, you just have to select the required commits and it merges it to the current branch. You can also fully automatize the task by running `git-cherry-pick` by hand, but you'll need the commit SHAs. HTH.

Comment: I am not very sure about my final needs myself, as a beginner. I see how gitk is very useful, so - thanks again. A couple of questions: 1) once I have displayed the differences in gitk, how do I merge or manually transfer source code changes if they do not coincide with commits? 2) if I operate using gitk, gitgui or gitbash, will eclipse/egit be able to keep up? e.g., what is checked out, merged, etc...?

Comment: Oh, so you want to merge in diffs, but not whole commits? Well, it can be done but it's far from trivial, I wouldn't suggest that: you have to rewrite the history and [http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History](split commits). 2) EGit can keep up, just don't forget to refresh the project (F5), older versions of Eclipse might need it.

Comment: I see. Thanks again. This conveniently points to further learning and indicates what is expected. Very useful. Till next time...