# How to merge git commits in the develop branch to a feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, feature-branch

I have a develop branch and a feature branch in my git repo. I added a commit to develop and now I want that commit to be merged to my feature branch. If I do this

```
git checkout feature
git merge develop
```

I end up with a merge commit. Since I'll be merging new commits on develop to my feature branch frequently, I'd like to avoid all these unnecessary merge commits. I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4556531/55948) that suggested doing a `git rebase develop` but it ends up rewinding my branch way too far and the rebase fails.

**Update:**
What I ended up doing was

```
git checkout feature
git merge develop # this creates a merge commit that I don't want
git rebase # this gets rid of the merge commit but keeps the commits from develop that I do want
git push
```

**Update:** I just noticed that the original commit on develop gets a different hash when I merge then rebase to the feature branch. I don't think that's what I want because eventually I'll merge feature back into develop and I'm guessing this won't play nice.

Comment: Hmm, well I know that you can "squash" your commits together when you rebase, as a way to not have so many commits on your branch. Check out http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html.

Comment: Rebasing *is* the answer, if it's not working for you, there's another question you should be asking about *why* it isn't working.

Answer (score 30):

To integrate one branch into another, you have to either merge or rebase. Since it's only safe to rebase commits that aren't referenced anywhere else (not merged to other local branches; not pushed to any remote), it's generally better to merge.

If your feature branch is purely local, you can rebase it on top of develop. However, it takes time to understand how rebase works, and before you do, it's quite easy to accidentally produce duplicated or dropped commits. Merge commits might look noisy but merging is guaranteed to always be safe and predictable.

For a better view, try logging everything together in a graph:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate
```

It's also worth considering whether you really *need* the commits on `develop` merged into `feature`. Often they're things that can be left seperate until `feature` is merged into `develop` later.

If you regularly find you do need `develop` code on `feature` then it might be a sign that your feature branches are too long-running. Ideally features should be split in such a way that they can be worked on independently, without needing regular integration along the way.

Answer (score 14):

If you only want one commit from the `develop` branch you can cherry-pick it in your `feature` branch:

```
 git checkout feature
 git cherry-pick -x <commit-SHA1>
```

The commit will be applied as a new one on top of your branch (provided it doesn't generate a conflict), and when you'll merge back the `feature` branch Git will cope with it without conflicts.

Comment: This is arguably a better alternative to a merge because it keeps the history clean when the feature will be merged back into develop